# NSURLSession member reference type struct objc_class is a pointer

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, nsurlsession

I'm trying to implement a singleton to manage NSURLSession request. Here is my code:

Header file:

```
@interface httpRequest : NSObject

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSURLSession *session;

+(httpRequest*)request;
```

Implementation file(.m):

```
+(httpRequest*)request
{
    static httpRequest *shareObject = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once ( &onceToken, ^{
        shareObject = [[self alloc] init];
        self.session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    });
    return shareObject;
}
```

But in this line:

```
self.session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
```

I'm getting this error: "NSURLSession member reference type struct objc_class is a pointer did you mean to use ->"

[image]
Why I'm getting error?, any of you knows a way around this?

Comment: Completely unrelated, you might consider following Cocoa naming conventions whereby class names start with an uppercase letter (e.g. `HTTPRequest` or `HttpRequest`). It is merely a convention, but it makes code a little easier to read. And, going even farther afield, I'm not sure I'd use `Request` in the name at all, because "request" is usually associated with a particular `NSURLSessionTask` (a particular request from a web service), not the `NSURLSession` itself. I might therefore name it `HTTPManager` or something like that to avoid the request/session naming confusion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way is to use the `init` method

```
+(httpRequest*)request
{
    static httpRequest *shareObject = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once ( &onceToken, ^{
        shareObject = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return shareObject;
}


- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
       }
    }
    return self;
}
```

But since `sharedObject` is actually `self` this is supposed to work, too

```
+(httpRequest*)request
{
    static httpRequest *shareObject = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once ( &onceToken, ^{
        shareObject = [[self alloc] init];
        shareObject.session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    });
    return shareObject;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In a class method (one that starts with `+`), `self` refers to the class, not the instance. I think you intended `shareObject.session`. Personally, I'd move the setting of the `session` to the `init` method (in which case, you would use the `self.session` syntax).

Or, in Objective-C you can now define `class` properties (designed for Swift interoperability). But, since you're only going to have one `httpRequest`, that's overkill.